# Play store saying supported device 0

Tags: android

I have tried all the ways to figure it out but unable to resolve. Below is my code snipeet of manifest and gradle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.datadrive"
    android:versionCode="39"
    android:versionName="1.34">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<!--    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false"/>-->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme_NoAction">
        <activity
            android:name="com.datadrive.activitites.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FullScreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.datadrive.activitites.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme_NoAction"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.datadrive.activities_new.MainActivitySecond"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme_NoAction"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.datadrive.activitites.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme_NoAction"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity android:name="com.datadrive.activitites.DemoActivity">
            <!--
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            -->
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.datadrive.activitites.ViewDetailsActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.datadrive.activitites.ViewDataBaseActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And below is my gradle code snippet :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.datadrive"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 39
        versionName "1.35"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile files('libs/simplelatlng-1.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/crittercism_v5_0_4_sdkonly.jar')
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
}
```

I have tried to upload my app's new version to play store and it is showing 0 supported devices.

For testing, I rollbacked my old version  changed only version code/name in gradle file and tried to upload the apk again. It is showing 0 supported devices too.

Few days ago, that version  supported more than 10000 devices.

Is it because google policy changed or I updated my gradle and android studio?

Comment: versionName "1.35" in gradle and in manifest it is versionName "1.34"

Comment: I have changed it to same version but still the issue is same, Please advise

Comment: what is the version of your android studio

Comment: Android studio version is : 2.2.1